# How can I prevent Google Chrome update from re-enabling integrated Flash plugin?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, flash-player

I frequently debug Flex applications in Google Chrome and use a debug version of Flash Player to get the job done. However, for some time now, Google Chrome has deployed an integrated version of Flash. Getting around that requires a few tweaks [as described over at Adobe's website](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/flash-player-google-chrome.html#main_I_am_a_developer__designer__or_advanced_user_that_creates_or_tests_Flash_content__How_can_I_run_debugger_or_alternate_versions_of_Flash_Player_in_Google_Chrome_).

Everything would be nice and beautiful if only Google Chrome updates would not mess around with those settings. Currently every time a new version of Chrome is pushed I get to scratch my head as to why Flex applications act weird - only to realize that chrome://plugins need yet another nudge.

**How can I prevent Google Chrome update from re-enabling integrated Flash plugin?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out this is a bug reported as [issue 150596](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=150596). Release 23 should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the answer you are looking for but how about installing a portable version of Google Chrome which (in theory) won't update itself automatically?

One suggestion would be the PortableApps version of Chrome:

http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/google_chrome_portable

Comment: Turning off updates is easy but that is not what I am after. It is the habit of Chrome update to unilaterally fiddle with manually modified plugin settings I want to get rid of.